# Drupal 7 not showing sub menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

i am new to drupal and creating custom theme, i am using Main Menu but it is now showing sub-pages, i am using following code to show.

```
print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix', 'main-menu'))));
```

Please let me know what to do ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Using this method will not render the sub items of a menu item. In order to have a menu with multiple levels you can either:

- Use the available `Main menu` block available under `admin/structure/block`
- Change the `$main_menu` variable passed to the template by using a `preprocess` function

**In `template.php` of your theme**:

```
function YOURTHEME_process_page(&$variables) {
    $menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
    $variables['main_menu'] = menu_tree_output($menu_tree);
}
```

**In your template file (`page.tpl.php`)**

```
<?php print render($main_menu); ?>
```